# Gmail IMAP issues

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to create a PHP script to look through my Gmail account.

I have successfully logged in, but found a few queries which i am unsure about

login script: (i am connected)

```
     $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}';
     $username = "USERNAME@gmail.com";
     $password = "PASSWORD";
     /* try to connect */
     $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/All Mail';

     /* try to connect */
     $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

code to loop through my emails :-

```
     $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
     /* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
     if($emails) {
     echo "FOUND EMAIlS<br />\n";
      $x=0;
      foreach ($emails as $ab => $email_number)
      {
      echo "'$ab '$email_number'<br />\n";
      $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
      echo " &nbsp; Ov = '$overview'<br />\n";
```

(I have a $x counter to stop the script after 20 emails)

**Issue 1:-**

If i use `print_r($overview);` it works perfectly fine - but if i use a foreach loop on the `$overview`, i get an error :-

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in (PATHNAME)  line 37

Just curious - why can i use `print_r` on an array, but not a foreach ? any reason ?

**issue 2 :-**

the "from" result displays the NAME of the person - "john smith". is there a way to get the email address ?

(i do see some email addresses in the TO field, if i didn't have them in my contacts. but not in the FROM field.)

**Issue 3:**

i did find a google search a few hours ago (but forgot to bookmark it), where you can use regular MYSQLI commands to search emails, but I couldn't get the PHP script to connect. So i started searching for a workig connect script.

Is there a different way to connect, so we can use regular MYSQL commands ?

Ultimate aim: to retrieve a list of all the FROM "email addresses" (not the name of the sender),  possibly a count of the emails too ?

I do have 30,000+ emails, & can do this process via a cron-job, over  a period of time - building up a list.

EDIT: When I inserted the print_r command, the email address of the FROM name was not one of the resuts retrieved

EDIT: added imap_open line

EDIT: OUTPUT OF PRINT_R($output);

```
     Array
     (
         [0] => stdClass Object
             (
                 [subject] => subject line of email
                 [from] => From name
                 [to] => emailaddress@toperson.com
                 [date] => Sat, 10 Jul 2004 03:13:12 +1200
                 [message_id] => <9a3273a0040709081340933b3a@mail.gmail.com>
                 [size] => 1132
                 [uid] => 27
                 [msgno] => 21
                 [recent] => 0
                 [flagged] => 0
                 [answered] => 0
                 [deleted] => 0
                 [seen] => 1
                 [draft] => 0
             )
     )
```

This is my oldest message. it does include the email address i sent the message TO, but not the email address of the FROM (some eamils are To me - but still do not show an email address of the sender)

Comment: where is line 37? MySQL command in IMAP ?

Comment: line 37: foreach ($emails as $ab => $email_number). I have now removed this & added the print_r command. forach produced the error.

Comment: Incorrect - FOREACH on $emails is ok.  its the foreach on the $overview value that caused the error. (now print_r)

Comment: what is the output of `print_r()` ?

Comment: By the way, consider to use: https://developers.google.com/gmail/

Comment: `print_r()` already told you that `$overview[0]` is a `stdClass ` Object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read it in this way:

```
foreach($overview as $entry) {
  $subject = $entry->subject;
}
```